# How to Nest query with different criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Sales_details table where I like to get a report of the top 150 products and the top 10 customers of each product.  The code I have below does just that and is working perfectly.  However, it is using the same date range for both. How do I modify this so that the top 150 products is based on a 10 years history while the top 10 customers is based on 2 years history?

```
    select pc.*
    from (select pc.*,
         dense_rank() over (order by product_sales desc, product_id) as product_rank
    from (select sd.product_id, sd.custno, sum(sd.sales$) as total_sales,
               row_number() over (partition by sd.product_id order by sum(sd.sales$) as cust_within_product_rank,
               sum(sum(sd.sales$)) over (partition by sd.product_id) as product_sales
        from salesdetails sd
        group by sd.product_id, sd.custno
       ) pc
    ) pc
    where product_rank <= 150 and cust_within_product_rank <= 10;
```

Comment: There appears to be ***no*** date range being used in this example?

Comment: Correct, the above example does not have any date so it is using the full data set for both query.  But assuming the date field is called date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select pc.*
from (select pc.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by product_sales desc, product_id) as product_rank
      from (select sd.product_id, sd.custno, sum(sd.sales$) as total_sales,
                   row_number() over (partition by sd.product_id 
                                      order by sum(case when date > dateadd(year, -2, getdate()) then sd.sales$ else 0 end)
                                     ) as cust_within_product_rank,
                    sum(sum(case when date > dateadd(year, -10, getdate()) then sd.sales$ else 0 end)) over (partition by sd.product_id) as product_sales
            from salesdetails sd
            group by sd.product_id, sd.custno
           ) pc
     ) pc
where product_rank <= 150 and cust_within_product_rank <= 10;
```

I'm not sure what column you use for `date`, so I just called it `date`.

Comment: Upvoted, though I would move the 10 year filter to the `WHERE` clause of the inner most query...